# Phaser 3, Uncaught TypeError: this.cameras.main.setMask is not a function when trying to apply mask to camera

Tags: mask, phaser-framework

I am trying to apply a 'fog of war' affect to my game and require the use of a mask over my camera. i have researched and followed the tutorial here - [Phaser demo sandbox](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cdisplay%5Cmasks%5CCamera%20Mask%20Test%205.js) - and after trying to do it myself i resulted in copying it. this still returns the same error and claims it cannot be applied. if i substiute `this.cameras.main` with player the game works but doesnt give desired outcome.

```
const maskImage = this.make.image({
    x: 400,
    y: 300,
    key: 'mask',
    add: false
});

const mask = maskImage.createBitmapMask();

this.cameras.main.setMask(mask);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean,, with substitute `this.cameras.main` with `player`, can you share more code? showing the problem you discribed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem - all the examples use `this.cameras.main.setMask` but that was undefined on the camera object in my project.

In my case, I'd followed the "Getting Started with Phaser 3" docs to get a basic scene set up and continued working with that, but that tutorial uses version 3.15.1, which is pretty out of date by now and doesn't have the `setMask` method on the camera object. Updating to 3.55.2 (the latest version as I'm writing this) fixed the problem.